# React Native image picker is showing image too slow after successfully uploading

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

after uploading image successfully the uploaded image is taking time to show ?
anyone knows anything about it?

here is my code

```js
  _onPressEdit = () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        this._uploadImage(response.uri);
      }
    });
  };
```

here is my full code

```js
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, PermissionsAndroid, Platform} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import styles from './styles';
import {Images, Styles, Language, Colors} from '@theme';
import {Wrapper, Input, ButtonView} from '@components';
import {TextInputField} from '@customComponents';
import {Navigator} from '@services';
import StarRating from 'react-native-star-rating';
import Header from '../Header';
import Footer from '../Footer';
import {uploadImage, editProfile} from '../../../actions/UserActions';

import {BASE_URL_PHOTO} from '../../../config/WebService';

import {selectUserData} from '../../../selectors/userSelector';
import {UserPresenter} from '../../../presenter';
import {Util} from '../../../utils';

const options = {
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images',
  },
};

class Profile extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const {firstName, lastName, email, mobile, image, id} = this.props.user;

    this.state = {
      id,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      mobile,
      image,
      errors: {},
    };
  }

  onStarRatingPress(rating) {
    this.setState({
      starCount: rating,
    });
  }

  checkAllPermissions = async () => {
    try {
      await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      ]);
      if (
        (await PermissionsAndroid.check('android.permission.CAMERA')) &&
        (await PermissionsAndroid.check('android.permission.CAMERA')) &&
        (await PermissionsAndroid.check('android.permission.CAMERA'))
      ) {
        this._onPressEdit();
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log('all permissions denied');
        return false;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };

  _onPressEdit = () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        this._uploadImage(response.uri);
      }
    });
  };

  _uploadImage = image => {
    const {uploadImage} = this.props;
    const {id} = this.props.user;

    UserPresenter.sendUploadAvatarRequest(
      uploadImage,
      image,
      id,
      this._onSuccessImageUpload,
    );
  };

  _onSuccessImageUpload = uri => {
    this.setState({
      image: uri,
    });
  };

  _onChangeText = (key, value) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        [key]: value,
      },
      () => console.log(this.state),
    );
  };

  _validateForm = () => {
    const {firstName, lastName, mobile} = this.state;

    const errors = UserPresenter.getEditProfileErrors(
      firstName,
      lastName,
      mobile,
    );

    this.setState({errors});

    return Util.isEmpty(errors);
  };

  _onPressSave = () => {
    const {firstName, lastName, mobile, image} = this.state;
    const {id} = this.props.user;
    const {editProfile} = this.props;

    if (this._validateForm()) {
      UserPresenter.sendEditProfileRequestStepOne(
        editProfile,
        id,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        mobile,
        image,
        this._onSuccessSave,
      );
    }
  };

  _onSuccessSave = () => {
    // Navigator.pop();
    Navigator.goBack();
  };

  _onPressNext = () => {
    if (this._validateForm()) {
      Navigator.navigate('EditProfileServices', {data: this.state});
    }
  };

  onPressFooterBtn = () => {
    Navigator.navigate('EditProfileServices');
  };

  renderStarRating() {
    const {rating} = this.props.user;

    return (
      <StarRating
        starSize={24}
        starStyle={styles.starStyle}
        halfStarEnabled={true}
        halfStarColor={Colors.textWhiteTwo}
        emptyStarColor={Colors.textWhiteTwo}
        disabled={true}
        maxStars={5}
        rating={rating}
        selectedStar={rating => this.onStarRatingPress(rating)}
      />
    );
  }

  renderEditFields() {
    const {firstName, lastName, email, mobile, errors} = this.state;

    return (
      <View>
        <TextInputField
          title={Language.firstName}
          placeholder={Language.Andrew}
          value={firstName}
          onChangeText={text => this._onChangeText('firstName', text)}
          error={errors.firstName}
        />
        <TextInputField
          title={Language.lastName}
          placeholder={Language.Crammer}
          value={lastName}
          onChangeText={text => this._onChangeText('lastName', text)}
          error={errors.lastName}
        />
        <TextInputField
          title={Language.email}
          keyboardType={'email-address'}
          placeholder={Language.andrewCrammerEmail}
          value={email}
          onChangeText={text => this._onChangeText('email', text)}
          error={errors.email}
          editable={false}
        />
        <TextInputField
          title={Language.phone}
          keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
          placeholder={Language.EditProfilePhonePlaceholder}
          value={mobile}
          onChangeText={text => this._onChangeText('mobile', text)}
          error={errors.mobileNumber}
        />
        {/* <Input
          label={Language.changePassword}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          placeholder={Language.EditProfileChangePassword}
        /> */}
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderBody() {
    const {rating} = this.props.user;
    const {image} = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={Styles.paddingHorizontal}>
        <View
          style={[
            Styles.flexDirectionRow,
            Styles.alignItemsCenter,
            styles.mb_30,
          ]}>
          <View style={styles.editProfileImgWrap}>
            <Image
              style={styles.imgStyle}
              source={{uri: `${BASE_URL_PHOTO}${image}`}}
            />
            <ButtonView
              isBackgroundRipple
              onPress={
                Platform.OS === 'android'
                  ? this.checkAllPermissions
                  : this._onPressEdit
              }
              style={[Styles.positionAbsolute, styles.editWrap]}>
              <Text style={styles.edit}>{Language.edit}</Text>
            </ButtonView>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{Language.ProfilePicture}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.starStyleWrap}>
          {this.renderStarRating()}
          <Text style={styles.starRatingText}>{rating}</Text>
        </View>
        <View>{this.renderEditFields()}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderHeader() {
    return <Header onPressSave={this._onPressSave} />;
  }

  renderFooter() {
    return <Footer onPressNext={this._onPressNext} step={1} />;
  }

  //Render
  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper
        header={this.renderHeader()}
        footer={this.renderFooter()}
        isFetching={this.props.isFetching}
        isAbsolute
        mainContainerStyle={Styles.paddingHorizontalNone}
        isScrollView>
        {this.renderBody()}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: selectUserData(state.user),
    isFetching: state.user.isFetching,
  };
};

const actions = {uploadImage, editProfile};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Profile);
```

Comment: Did you enable the debugging mode on emulator or device ?

Comment: yes, but it is working slow on release build as well

Comment: If you can attach screen recording with your question

Comment: @AkilaDevinda https://youtu.be/VcQrEOeLcEo here you go
my question is simple that after uploading image on server successfully why it is taking time to show?
why is my image changing too late?

Answer (score 1):

issue solved 
just compress your image size so it wont take time to appear

here is the code

```js
const options = {
  title: 'Select Picture',
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images',
  },
  maxWidth: 500,
  maxHeight: 500,
  quality: 0.5,
};
```

previous code was

```js
const options = {
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images',
  },
};
```